# Javascript returns wrong Date values (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I'm working on a NodeJS Projects and I get wrong Date values. And I don't get what I am doing wrong.

```
 var d = new Date(results[1].timestamp);
      console.log(results[1].timestamp); // 2016-05-10T13:29:47   <- this is right (stored at my DataBase)
      console.log(d.getDate());          //10
      console.log(d.getFullYear());      //2016
      console.log(d.getMonth());         //4
      console.log(d.getDay());           //2
      console.log(d.getHours());         //15
      console.log(d.getMinutes());       //29
      console.log(d.getSeconds());       //47
```

So Month, Day and Hours are wrong.
I see these results in google chrome at my Mac

Thanks for helping

Comment: Did you read the documentation for getDay and getMonth ? I don't think you did...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few errors here:

1. `getMonth` returns a `0` based month. That is May is `04`.
2. `getDay` returns the day of the week. I guess you want `getDate`
3. the date is parsed as UTC and `getHour` is according to the locale. So the hour might be different from what you want (but right here it seems to be "exact", as is it's the same value than inputted).

A tip for your next problems: Have a look at some documentation. For example [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 2):

[The getDay() method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp)

[The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp)

[The getHours() method returns the hour (from 0 to 23) of the specified date and time.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp)

Answer (score 2):

`getDay()` function returns the Day of the date i.e. from sunday to saturday(0 to 6)

`getMonth()` function returns month frome January to December (0 to 1) so here you need to add 1 to correctly get the value

and I am afraid you misinterpreted `getHours()` result, because if I check for the mentioned date it gives me 13